# xlsxwriter chart create dynamic rows

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to create charts with xlsxwriter python module.
It works fine, but I would like to not have to hard code the row amount
This example will chart 30 rows.

```
chart.add_series({
   'name':   'SNR of old AP',
   'values': '=Depart!$D$2:$D$30',
   'marker': {'type': 'circle'},
   'data_labels': {'value': True,'num_format':'#,##0'},
})
```

For values': I would like the row count to be dynamic. How do I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works fine, but I would like to not have to hard code the row amount

XlsxWriter supports a list syntax in `add_series()` for this exact case. So your example could be written as:

```
chart.add_series({
   'name':   'SNR of old AP',
   'values': ['Depart', 1, 3, 29, 3],
   'marker': {'type': 'circle'},
   'data_labels': {'value': True, 'num_format':'#,##0'},
})
```

And then you can set any of the `first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col` parameters programmatically.

See the docs for [add_series()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-add-series).